# Multiple Easy VPN on Cisco Small Business RV325

Tags: cisco, vpn

I'm trying to figure out where is the problem.

**The router**

A Cisco small business RV 325.

**Configuration**

I have set two Easy VPNs with different pre-shared keys.

The first one, "ManagementVPN" should lead to a 192.168.98.1/24 LAN with DHCP Enabled (I created a VLAN and a DHCP server)

The other one should lead to a 192.168.42.1/24 (DHCP Enabled).

Both links can be connected but both give me an IP in 42 range. Both links are set with the "Split tunnel" option.

I created two users, both are with an unassigned group membership. The first is destined to reach the first VPN and the second the other VPN.

**Client to Gateway config (2nd VPN)**

[image: Configuration for 2nd VLAN]

The first VLAN has the same config, but the IP Address is set to 192.168.98.0

**Issue summary**

It's as if the tunnel was established with the wrong shared key, or the second was used anyway.

I used Windows 7 connectivity tool to connect to the VPN.

Any clue?

Comment: Can you post your config?  The problem is probably in the group membership

Comment: The router is managed through a web interface.
Which parts of the config are useful ?
The link below shows the interface : 
https://www.cisco.com/assets/sol/sb/RV325_Emulators/RV325_Emulator_v1-1-0-09/default.htm

Comment: Post the client to gateway VPN page

Comment: Hi, I uploaded the config.

Comment: Try remove space from tunel name

Comment: Hi, thanks. I've tried removing spaces. It didn't change anything. By the way, I've found the root cause to this assignment: the PPTP server is active and uses the same IP range. So, basically, those tunnels are not used... But, if I deactivate the PPTP server, I don't have VPN access anymore (via Windows VPN). Via Linux and Mac, I can't connect even with that PPTP server active.